# Selenium PATH Difficulty

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException, NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from random import randint, randrange
#from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
import time
import random

BESTBUY_URL = 'https://www.bestbuy.com/site/sony-playstation-5-digital-edition-console/6430161.p?skuId=6430161'
BESTBUY_TEST_URL = 'https://www.bestbuy.com/site/sony-playstation-5-dualsense-wireless-controller-cosmic-red/6464309.p?skuId=6464309'
WAIT_TIME = 7
PRICE_LIMIT = 500
class Zac:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        #binary = FirefoxBinary("/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin")
        #self.driver = webdriver.Firefox("Applications/Firefox.app")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Applications/Google Chrome.app")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.



    def signIn(self): 
        driver = self.driver

        ##Username
        username_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("_____")
        username_elem.clear()
        username_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        
        time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))
        username_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))

        ##Password

        password_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("_____")
        password_elem.clear()
        password_elem.send_keys(self.password)

        time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))
        password_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))

    def findProduct(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(BESTBUY_TEST_URL)
        time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))

        isAvailable = self.isProductAvailable()

        if isAvailable == 'Sold Out':
            time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))
            self.findProduct()
        elif isAvailable <= PRICE_LIMIT:

            buy_now = driver.find_by_name('submit.buy-now')
            buy_now.click()
            time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))
            self.signIn()

           ##Place Order
            place_order = driver.find_element_by_name('placeYourOrder1').text
            time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))
            ## place_order.click()
            ## time.sleep(randict(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))

        else:
            time.sleep(randint(int(WAIT_TIME/2), WAIT_TIME))
            self.findProduct()

    def isProductAvailable(self):
        driver = self.driver
        available = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-color-price').text
        if available == 'Currently unavailable.':
            print(f'***** AVAILABLE: {available}')
            return available
        else:
            print(f'***** PRICE: {available}')
            return float(available[1:]) ## $123.22 -> 123. 22

    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    shopBot = Zac(username="_____", password="_____")
    shopBot.findProduct()
    shopBot.closeBrowser()
```

For some reason, it is saying that Google Chrome.app executable needs to be in PATH. I am trying to make a scalping bot, and this seems to be my biggest mistake area. I am open to using any browser that is easiest. As you can see in the code I first tried this with FireFox. If anybody could help that would be greatly appreciated.